# The / keeps on coming automatically

Tags: keyboard

The slash keeps on repeating itself automatically even if I don't use the keyboard. Whatever editors I use, it comes automatically for sometime. 
I wanted to ask whether its triggered automatically by some virus attacks or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Clean (NO WATER!) or Replace your keyboard. Is anything stuck under/around the <kbd>/</kbd> key? This is hardware, not software.

Comment: Nothing got stuck in between. It happened to my friends laptop too. I guess it could be a virus. Better to change this problem than to replace the keyboard.